# Used Disk Utility to Format a Flash Drive as exFAT but Returns as NTFS

Tags: disk-utility

I format a flash drive as exFAT on macOS (M1 Pro) but after the format, `diskutil list` shows the partition as NTFS and it also shows up as NTFS on OpenBSD and Linux. This is strange and I’m not sure what is happening

Comment: What does `mount -t exfat` show?

Comment: Are you sure you formatted the correct drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the flash drive is using the Master Boot Record partition map, then an ExFAT formatted partition will be given the ID of 7. A NTFS formatted partition is also given an ID of 7. The `TYPE` column output from the `diskutil list` command uses character strings to identify IDs. The ID of 7 has been assigned the string `Windows_NTFS`. This does not mean the partition is necessarily formatted NTFS. In your case, the partition is formatted ExFAT.

Below is part of the output from `diskutil list` taken from my Mac.

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +16.0 GB    disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS MyFlash                 16.0 GB    disk1s1
```

This output shows the drive has an identifier of `disk1` and the ExFAT formatted partition has the identifier of `disk1s1`. Below is the output from the command `fdisk /dev/disk1` which shows the ID is 7.

```
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 1945/255/63 [31250063 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -   31250062] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Below is the output from the command `diskutil info disk1s1 | grep Personality` which shows the partition is ExFAT formatted.

```
   File System Personality:  ExFAT
```

### References

- [List of partition IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs)